# add border to the bottom of div after image inside carousel in bootstrap4

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to place a blue border at the end of the images that are inside the carousel, but I could not, this is my HTML code for the carousel. how could you add that border ?, the top border of the image is blue, the same border has to be at the bottom after the image, please help this is my CSS and HTML code

```
<div class="row fila2">
  <!----inicio columna 2----->              
  <div class="col-12 imagenesc">   
    <!----inicio carousel----->      
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="imagenes/20130819180556.jpg" alt="First slide">
        </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="imagenes/20130819180644.jpg" alt="Second slide">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev"> 
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>    
    </a> 
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next"> 
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
      <span class="sr-only">Nextborder</span> 
    </a><!----fin carousel----->      
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: can you provide any screenshot as you want..?

Comment: there is someway to expand the entire images?, i use the property                 .fila2 img { max-width: 100%; border-bottom: 2px solid green; }, but the border doesn´t expand entirely because de image,

Comment: Please check my ans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this. Its working. Please remove `row` and `col-12` class.

```css
.fila2 img { 
  max-width: 100%; 
  border: 5px solid #219ED6;       
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="fila2">
  <!----inicio columna 2----->              
  <div class="imagenesc">   
    <!----inicio carousel----->      
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://dummyimage.com/1920x700/000/fff.jpg&text=sample+image" alt="First slide">
        </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://dummyimage.com/1920x700/000/fff.jpg&text=sample+image2" alt="Second slide">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev"> 
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>    
    </a> 
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next"> 
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
      <span class="sr-only">Nextborder</span> 
    </a><!----fin carousel----->      
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ankita, could be someway to draw the entire border,? no only the image border?

Comment: Means you want to draw whole side of image border right..?

Comment: thanks ankita, you are a master, but i have a question for you, it might be some other way to drawn the border around the div, not the image.?

Comment: @RicardoRoa , yes you can also give border in `.fila2 .carousel-item{border: 5px solid #219ED6; }` class.